# Interpreting char as hex

Tags: matlab

I want to interpret (not convert) ascii chars as their hex values. I.e., I have `string = 'a';` It should be converted to hex value **0xa**.

I only found solutions which convert the ascii value into its hex representation (which would be 0x61 but which is not the value I am looking for).

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hex2dec.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Answer (score 2):

Use `hex2dec`:

```
string = 'a'
numericvalue = hex2dec(string)
```

Documentation here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hex2dec.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Internally, the value `0xa` is not stored as hex, or decimal, but as binary. But the number **value** is always the same, whether you write is as 10 (decimal), 0xa (hex), or 1010 (binary).

Answer (score 0):

Matlab doesn't have a hex type but you probably want something like this.

```
sscanf('a','%x')
```

which would result an answer of 10. converting back to hex w/ dec2hex would recreate a string representation.